# React app with Vimeo private video stream

Tags: reactjs, vimeo

I'm building a react webapp that streams private videos from vimeo. I have tried a couple of solutions like react-video-js-player, react-vimeo, some lite-vimeo-embed.

I get the links from the api response but since they are signature signed it gives error, the iframe works, but I have problems with delay in loading and it gives 404 while doing so.
Here are the solutions below:

```
<section id="content-app" className="content-app">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="section-header">  
                        <div className="section-header-left">
                            <h5>{videos.link}</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* <h4>{videos.link}</h4> */}
                    <lite-vimeo videoid={videos.id}></lite-vimeo>
                    <Vimeo
                        video={videos.id}
                        autoplay
                    />
                    <iframe src={`${videos.link}`} loading="lazy" class="lazyload"  data-src="https://www.wpclipart.com/blanks/buttons/glossy_buttons/glossy_button_blank_orange_rectangle.png" title={videos.name} width="100%" height="800px" frameBorder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
                    <VideoPlayer
                        controls={true}
                        src={videos.link}
                        poster={this.state.video.poster}
                        height="420"
                        onReady={this.onPlayerReady.bind(this)}
                        onPlay={this.onVideoPlay.bind(this)}
                        onPause={this.onVideoPause.bind(this)}
                        onTimeUpdate={this.onVideoTimeUpdate.bind(this)}
                        onSeeking={this.onVideoSeeking.bind(this)}
                        onSeeked={this.onVideoSeeked.bind(this)}
                        onEnd={this.onVideoEnd.bind(this)}
                    />
                   
                </div>
            </section>
```

Any help will be appreciated.